# How to distribute $n$ points in a sphere to maximize the angle between them?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Assume there are $n$ points $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ on the sphere of a $d$-dimensional unit ball. Let $\theta_{ij}$ denote the angle between $x_i$ and $x_j$. How to choose those $n$ points to maximize $\min_{i,j} \theta_{ij}$?

When $d = 2$, I think we can simply consider the
regular polygon with $n$ vertices and $\max \min_{i,j}\theta_{ij} = \frac{2\pi}{n}$. But for $d \geq 3$, it is hard to imagine.

Comment: It seems this is a tricky problem in general. See http://neilsloane.com/packings/index.html

Comment: @JairTaylor Thanks for the reference!

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem